# Orientation change bug

Tags: android, android-orientation

I use `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` in my activites.

My application turns to landscape mode just for a very short duration like about 0.2 seconds if i change betwen activities. After the ladnscape change it is changes back to portrait but it is very annoying bug.

Why is it happening ? Is there a better way to restrict the application to only use PORTRAIT orientation?

I dont want the 0.2 sec flashy orientation change.

Comment: Did you try android:configChanges="orientation" in your activity declaration in manifest?

Comment: android:screenOrientation="portrait" for all activites in manifest.

Comment: You should look at this question. Seems like the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885620/force-portrait-orientation-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your `Activities` to be in `portrait` all the time, you should specify the `android:screenOrientation:"portrait"` xml tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` for each `<activity>` tag.