# Convert magnetic field X, Y, Z values from device into global reference frame

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, magnetometer

When you use TYPE_MAGNETOMETER sensor, you get X, Y, Z values of magnetic field strength in relation to the device orientation. What I want to get is to convert these values into global reference frame, clarifying: user takes the device, measure these values, than rotate the device for some degrees around any axis and gets ~the same values.
Please, find similar questions below:
[Getting magnetic field values in global coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361010/getting-magnetic-field-values-in-global-coordinates)
[How can I get the magnetic field vector, independent of the device rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772923/how-can-i-get-the-magnetic-field-vector-independent-of-the-device-rotation)
In this answer sample solution is described (it is for linear acceleration, but I think it doesn't matter): https://stackoverflow.com/a/11614404/2152255
I used it and I got 3 values, X is always very small (don't think that it is correct), Y and Z are OK, but they still changed a bit when I rotate the device. How could it be adjusted? And could it be solved all? I use simple Kalman filter to approximate measurement values, because w/o it I get quiet different values even if the device is not moving/rotating at all. Please, find my code below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.test.statistics.filter.kalman.KalmanState;
import com.example.R;

/**
 * Activity for gathering magnetic field statistics.
 */
public class MagneticFieldStatisticsGatheringActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    public static final int KALMAN_STATE_MAX_SIZE = 80;
    public static final double MEASUREMENT_NOISE = 5;

    /** Sensor manager. */
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    /** Magnetometer spec. */
    private TextView vendor;
    private TextView resolution;
    private TextView maximumRange;

    /** Magnetic field coordinates measurements. */
    private TextView magneticXTextView;
    private TextView magneticYTextView;
    private TextView magneticZTextView;

    /** Sensors. */
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private Sensor mGeomagnetic;
    private float[] accelerometerValues;
    private float[] geomagneticValues;

    /** Flags. */
    private boolean specDefined = false;
    private boolean kalmanFiletring = false;

    /** Rates. */
    private float nanoTtoGRate = 0.00001f;
    private final int gToCountRate = 1000000;

    /** Kalman vars. */
    private KalmanState previousKalmanStateX;
    private KalmanState previousKalmanStateY;
    private KalmanState previousKalmanStateZ;
    private int previousKalmanStateCounter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mGeomagnetic = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

        vendor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vendor);
        resolution = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resolution);
        maximumRange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maximumRange);

        magneticXTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.magneticX);
        magneticYTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.magneticY);
        magneticZTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.magneticZ);

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGeomagnetic, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh statistics.
     *
     * @param view - refresh button view.
     */
    public void onClickRefreshMagneticButton(View view) {
        resetKalmanFilter();
    }

    /**
     * Switch Kalman filtering on/off
     *
     * @param view - Klaman filetring switcher (checkbox)
     */
    public void onClickKalmanFilteringCheckBox(View view) {
        CheckBox kalmanFiltering = (CheckBox) view;
        this.kalmanFiletring = kalmanFiltering.isChecked();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE) {
            return;
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            switch(sensorEvent.sensor.getType()){
                case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                    accelerometerValues = sensorEvent.values.clone();
                    break;
                case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                    if (!specDefined) {
                        vendor.setText("Vendor: " + sensorEvent.sensor.getVendor() + " " + sensorEvent.sensor.getName());
                        float resolutionValue = sensorEvent.sensor.getResolution() * nanoTtoGRate;
                        resolution.setText("Resolution: " + resolutionValue);
                        float maximumRangeValue = sensorEvent.sensor.getMaximumRange() * nanoTtoGRate;
                        maximumRange.setText("Maximum range: " + maximumRangeValue);
                    }
                    geomagneticValues = sensorEvent.values.clone();
                    break;
            }
            if (accelerometerValues != null && geomagneticValues != null) {
                float[] Rs = new float[16];
                float[] I = new float[16];

                if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(Rs, I, accelerometerValues, geomagneticValues)) {

                    float[] RsInv = new float[16];
                    Matrix.invertM(RsInv, 0, Rs, 0);

                    float resultVec[] = new float[4];
                    float[] geomagneticValuesAdjusted = new float[4];
                    geomagneticValuesAdjusted[0] = geomagneticValues[0];
                    geomagneticValuesAdjusted[1] = geomagneticValues[1];
                    geomagneticValuesAdjusted[2] = geomagneticValues[2];
                    geomagneticValuesAdjusted[3] = 0;
                    Matrix.multiplyMV(resultVec, 0, RsInv, 0, geomagneticValuesAdjusted, 0);

                    for (int i = 0; i < resultVec.length; i++) {
                        resultVec[i] = resultVec[i] * nanoTtoGRate * gToCountRate;
                    }

                    if (kalmanFiletring) {

                        KalmanState currentKalmanStateX = new KalmanState(MEASUREMENT_NOISE, accelerometerValues[0], (double)resultVec[0], previousKalmanStateX);
                        previousKalmanStateX = currentKalmanStateX;

                        KalmanState currentKalmanStateY = new KalmanState(MEASUREMENT_NOISE, accelerometerValues[1], (double)resultVec[1], previousKalmanStateY);
                        previousKalmanStateY = currentKalmanStateY;

                        KalmanState currentKalmanStateZ = new KalmanState(MEASUREMENT_NOISE, accelerometerValues[2], (double)resultVec[2], previousKalmanStateZ);
                        previousKalmanStateZ = currentKalmanStateZ;

                        if (previousKalmanStateCounter == KALMAN_STATE_MAX_SIZE) {
                            magneticXTextView.setText("x: " + previousKalmanStateX.getX_estimate());
                            magneticYTextView.setText("y: " + previousKalmanStateY.getX_estimate());
                            magneticZTextView.setText("z: " + previousKalmanStateZ.getX_estimate());

                            resetKalmanFilter();
                        } else {
                            previousKalmanStateCounter++;
                        }

                    } else {
                        magneticXTextView.setText("x: " + resultVec[0]);
                        magneticYTextView.setText("y: " + resultVec[1]);
                        magneticZTextView.setText("z: " + resultVec[2]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void resetKalmanFilter() {
        previousKalmanStateX = null;
        previousKalmanStateY = null;
        previousKalmanStateZ = null;
        previousKalmanStateCounter = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
    }
}
```

Thanks everybody who read this post and who post some thoughts about the problem in advance.

Comment: Can you share com.test.statistics.filter.kalman.KalmanState code? I need to filter sensor output with Kalman Filter.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In my comment on the checked answer on the link you provided above, I referred to my simple answer at [calculate acceleration in reference to true north](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963190/calculate-acceleration-in-reference-to-true-north/14988559#14988559)

Let me answer here again with more clarification. The answer is the product of the **rotation matrix** and the **magnetic field values**. If you read further on the "X is always very small" is the correct value.

The accelerometer and magnetic field sensors measure the acceleration of the device and the magnetic field of the earth at the device location respectively. They are vectors in 3 dimentional space, let call them **a** and **m** respectively.
If you stand still and rotate your device, theoretically **m** does not change assuming there are no magnetic interference from surrounding objects (actually **m** should change little, if you move around since the magnetic field of the earth should change little in a short distance). But `a` does change, even though it should not be drastic in most situation.

Now a vector **v** in 3 dimensional space can be represented by a 3-tuples (v_1, v_2, v_3) with respect to some basis (**e_1**, **e_2**, **e_3**), i.e **v** = v_1 **e_1** + v_2 **e_2** + v_3 **e_3**. (v_1, v_2, v_3) are called the coordinates of **v** with respect to the basis (**e_1**, **e_2**, **e_3**).

In Android devices, the basis is (**x**, **y**, **z**) where, for most phone, **x** is along the shorter side and pointing right, **y** is along the longer side and pointing up and **z** is perpendicular to the screen and pointing out.
Now this basis changes as the position of the device changes. One can think these bases as a function of time (**x**(t), **y**(t), **z**(t)), in mathematics term it is a moving coordinate system.

Thus even though **m** does not change, but the **event.values** returns by the sensors are different because the basis is different (I will talk about fluctuation later). As is, the **event.values** are useless because it gives us the coordinates but we do not know what the basis is, i.e with respect to some basis we know.

Now the question is: is it possible to find the coordinates of **a** and **m** with respect to the fixed world basis (**w_1**, **w_2**, **w_3**) where **w_1** points toward East, **w_2** points toward magnetic North and **w_3** points up toward the sky?

**The answer is yes provided 2 important assumptions are satisfied.**
With these 2 assumptions it is simple to calculate (just a few cross products) the change of basis matrix **R** from the basis (**x**, **y**, **z**) to the basis (**w_1**, **w_2**, **w_3**), which in Android is called the **Rotation matrix**. Then the coordinates of a vector **v** with respect to the basis (**w_1**, **w_2**, **w_3**) is obtained by multiply **R** with the coordinates of **v** with respect to (**x**, **y**, **z**). Thus the coordinates of **m** with respect to the world coordinates system is just the product of the **rotation matrix** and the **event.values** returned by the TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD sensor and similarly for **a**.

In android the **rotation matrix** is obtained by calling **getRotationMatrix (float[] R, float[] I, float[] gravity, float[] geomagnetic)** and we normally pass in the returned accelerometer values for the gravity parameter and the magnetic field values for the geomagnetic.

The **2 important assumptions** are:
**1-** The **gravity parameter** represents a vector lying in **w_3**, more particular it is the minus of the vector influenced by gravity alone.
Thus if you pass in the accelerometer values without filtering, the **rotation matrix** will be slightly off. That is why you need to filter the accelerometer so that the filter values are approximately just the minus gravity vector. Since the gravitational acceleration is the dominant factor in the accelerometer vector, normally low pass filter is sufficient.
**2-** The **geomagnetic parameter** represents a vector lying in the plane spanned by the **w_2** and the **w_3** vectors. That is it lies in the North-Sky plane. Thus in term of the (**w_1**, **w_2**, **w_3**) basis, the first coordinate should be 0. Therefore, the "X is always very small" as you stated it above is the correct value, ideally it should be 0. Now the magnetic field values will fluctuate quite a bit. This is kind of expected, just as a regular compass needle will not stand still if you keep it in your hand and your hand shakes a little. Also, you may get interference from objects surround you and in this case the magnetic field values are unpredictable. I once test my compass app sitting near a "stone" table and my compass was off by more than 90 degrees, only by using a real compass that I found out that there is nothing wrong with my app and the "stone" table produces a real strong magnetic field.
With gravity as a dominant factor you can filter accelerometer values, but without any other knowledge, how do you fitler magnetic values? How do you know if there is or isn't any interference from surrounding objects?

You can do a lot more like complete knowledge of your device spatial position etc with the understanding of **rotation matrix**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it clarified a lot of details that I didn't understand before. I will take it into account and correct my code.

Comment: You can check if the device has TYPE_GRAVITY and use it instead of TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, which save you the processing of Kalman filter.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to try it, but unfortunately my device has no TYPE_GRAVITY available. I'm planning also try another device with it a bit later.

Comment: Depending on what you do, Kalman filter might be overkill. For compass or augmented reality apps, low pass filter should be enough. I do not know what Kalman filter is but I heard that it is cpu intensive.

Comment: I have another question, TYPE_ACCELEROMETER as I understand is actually smth like TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION + TYPE_GRAVITY, isn't it? Is it ok to pass to getRotationMatrix values from TYPE_GRAVITY? Will it be more accurate when the device is moving (i read that if the device is accelerating, getRotationMatrix output is not accurate).

Comment: Yes, you can pass values from TYPE_GRAVITY. I think TYPE_GRAVITY is just TYPE_ACCELEROMETER with some kind of filter. I do not know how google implements it, thus I do not know if it will be more accurate. When the device is accelerating, the values pass in for the gravity parameter will not accurate approximate gravity, even when filter. Therefore, assumptions 1 is not quite satisfied and the output will be off. The getRotationMatrix use the gravity parameter as the Sky coordinate.

Comment: "When the device is accelerating, the values pass in for the gravity parameter will not accurate approximate gravity, even when filter" - absolutely correct, TYPE_ACCELEROMETER values are just unusable for getting rotation matrix when the device is accelerating. What I think is that TYPE_GRAVITY values are not changed or changed not so much

Comment: I compare TYPE_GRAVITY and low pass filter TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, the values are the same when the device is not moving, but once I rotated the device quickly, the differences can be up to 10 degrees.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Today I will get the device with TYPE_GRAVITY sensor and try to use it also and than come back with the results.

Comment: I think any device will have TYPE_GRAVITY, as long as the android API is 9 or up. In your project you can set the target to the latest and checking for version on the phone to turn on TYPE_GRAVITY.

Comment: @HoanNguyen thank you for the detailed answer. However, when I remove the gravity influence from acceleration (returned from TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) `getRotationMatrix` fails to compute `R` because "device is in free fall"? What am I missing here?

Comment: You should pass in the gravity and not the remove gravity. Thus if you use TYPE_ACCELEROMETER than filter out acceleration instead of gravity.

Comment: @HoanNguyen thanks for your explanation,Can you guide me about this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137239/get-moving-device-direction-without-gps

Answer (score 8):

As per the above explanation, do this

```
private static final int TEST_GRAV = Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER;
private static final int TEST_MAG = Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD;
private final float alpha = (float) 0.8;
private float gravity[] = new float[3];
private float magnetic[] = new float[3];

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
    if (sensor.getType() == TEST_GRAV) {
            // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.
              gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
              gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
              gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];
    } else if (sensor.getType() == TEST_MAG) {

            magnetic[0] = event.values[0];
            magnetic[1] = event.values[1];
            magnetic[2] = event.values[2];

            float[] R = new float[9];
            float[] I = new float[9];
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, gravity, magnetic);
            float [] A_D = event.values.clone();
            float [] A_W = new float[3];
            A_W[0] = R[0] * A_D[0] + R[1] * A_D[1] + R[2] * A_D[2];
            A_W[1] = R[3] * A_D[0] + R[4] * A_D[1] + R[5] * A_D[2];
            A_W[2] = R[6] * A_D[0] + R[7] * A_D[1] + R[8] * A_D[2];

            Log.d("Field","\nX :"+A_W[0]+"\nY :"+A_W[1]+"\nZ :"+A_W[2]);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Stochastically](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2110762/stochastically) has put an answer together that I find superior to what's being posted here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16418016/4033525

It seems `SensorManager.getOrientation()` fails to translate to the world frame correctly.

The correct code would be:

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(gravityCompassRotationMatrix, inclinationValues, gravityValues, magnitudeValues);
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(currentOrientationRotationMatrix.matrix, worldAxisX, worldAxisY, adjustedRotationMatrix);
float sin = adjustedRotationMatrix[1] - adjustedRotationMatrix[4];
float cos = adjustedRotationMatrix[0] + adjustedRotationMatrix[5];
float m_azimuth_radians = (float) (sin != 0 && cos != 0 ? Math.atan2(sin, cos) : 0);
```