# the getorientation() returns o.o always

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sensors, android-orientation

```
    boolean sensor=sensorManager.getRotationMatrix(orentation_factr,inclination,mGravity,mMagnetic);
if(sensor) {
    sensorManager.getOrientation(orentation_factr, orientation_angle);
    Log.e("testore_0", "true " + orientation_angle[0]);
}else{Log.e("testore_0", "false");}
```

this is what i tried, the return value from the getrotationmatrix is always false. so the getoreintation gives 0.0

this is the whole class.

```
public class AndroidAccelerometerExample extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

public Vibrator v;
int orientation;
float[] orentation_factr = new float[9];
float[] orientation_angle = new float[9];
float[] inclination = new float[9];
private float lastX, lastY, lastZ;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor accelerometer;
private float deltaX = 0;
private float deltaY = 0;
private float deltaZ = 0;
private float vibrateThreshold = 0;
private TextView currentX, currentY, currentZ;
private float[] mGravity = new float[3];
private float[] mMagnetic = new float[3];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeViews();
    mGravity = new float[3];
    mMagnetic = new float[3];
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) != null) {
        // success! we have an accelerometer

        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
       //magnetometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        vibrateThreshold = accelerometer.getMaximumRange() / 2;
    } else {
        // fai! we dont have an accelerometer!
    }

    //initialize vibration
    v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

}

public void initializeViews() {
    currentX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentX);
    currentY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentY);
    currentZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentZ);

}

//onResume() register the accelerometer for listening the events
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

//onPause() unregister the accelerometer for stop listening the events
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    displayCleanValues();
    displayCurrentValues();

    // get the change of the x,y,z values of the accelerometer
    deltaX = Math.abs(lastX - event.values[0]);
    deltaY = Math.abs(lastY - event.values[1]);
    deltaZ = Math.abs(lastZ - event.values[2]);

    // if the change is below 2, it is just plain noise
    if (deltaX < 2)
        deltaX = 0;
    if (deltaY < 2)
        deltaY = 0;
    if (deltaZ < 2)
        deltaZ = 0;

    // set the last know values of x,y,z
    lastX = event.values[0];
    lastY = event.values[1];
    lastZ = event.values[2];

    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            mGravity = event.values.clone();

            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            mMagnetic = event.values.clone();
            break;
    }

    boolean sensor = sensorManager.getRotationMatrix(orentation_factr, inclination, mGravity, mMagnetic);
    if (sensor) {
        sensorManager.getOrientation(orentation_factr, orientation_angle);
        Log.e("testore_0", "true " + orientation_angle[0]);
    } else {
        Log.e("testore_0", "false");
    }

    vibrate();
    orentationchange(event);
}

public void orentationchange(SensorEvent event) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            RotateAnimation animation = null;
            if (event.values[0] < 4 && event.values[0] > -4) {
                if (event.values[1] > 0 && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                    // UP
                    orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90;

                    Log.e("test", "up");
                } else if (event.values[1] < 0 && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                    // UP SIDE DOWN
                    Log.e("test", "down");
                    orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270;
                }
            } else if (event.values[1] < 4 && event.values[1] > -4) {
                if (event.values[0] > 0 && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) {
                    // LEFT
                    Log.e("test", "left");
                    orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
                } else if (event.values[0] < 0 && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                    // RIGHT
                    Log.e("test", "right");
                    orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180;
                }
            }
            if (animation != null) {
            }
        }

    }
}

public void vibrate() {
    if ((deltaX > vibrateThreshold) || (deltaY > vibrateThreshold) || (deltaZ > vibrateThreshold)) {
        v.vibrate(50);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Math.cos(Math.toRadians(50)) + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void displayCleanValues() {
    currentX.setText("0.0");
    currentY.setText("0.0");
    currentZ.setText("0.0");
}

// display the current x,y,z accelerometer values
public void displayCurrentValues() {
    currentX.setText(Float.toString(deltaX));
    currentY.setText(Float.toString(deltaY));
    currentZ.setText(Float.toString(deltaZ));
}
}
```

Comment: Try to read this answer it may helps : [Not able to fetch correct degree from getOrientation method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315970/not-able-to-fetch-correct-degree-from-getorientation-method)

Answer (score 0):

Pitch is calculated as pitch = (float) Math.asin(-RMatrix[7]); The range of the arcsin function is [-PI/2, PI/2], so asin can only take value in between -PI/2 and PI/2.