# Finding Azimuth Value when Device is not FLAT to ground - Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, android-orientation, device-orientation

I want to find the Azimuth angle of device when It is not FLAT to the ground.

**Here is an already existing Answer but not complete for me:**

Here is the accepted answer on this question, which is almost same. [Inconsistent orientation sensor values on Android for azimuth/yaw and roll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537125/inconsistent-orientation-sensor-values-on-android-for-azimuth-yaw-and-roll)

**Problem:**

But in this question, accepted answer gives azimuth value in the range -89 to 89. I want to calculate Azimuth angle value in range `0-359 degree`, when moving from Magnetic North. How can I calculate that in Android Sensors?

Comment: What do you want to do when the device is not flat? what direction do you want to obtain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found its answer:

**Calculate azimuth angle like this:**

```
mAzimuthAngleNotFlat = (int) Math.toDegrees(Math
                    .atan2((rotationMatrix[1] - rotationMatrix[3]), (rotationMatrix[0] + rotationMatrix[4])));
```

**To convert it to 0 to 359 simply apply this:**

```
    if (mAzimuthAngleNotFlat < 0) {
        mAzimuthAngleNotFlat += 360;
    }
```

Then you are done. And this angle will be accurate when device is not flat. For more, you can see discussion on accepted answer.

[Inconsistent orientation sensor values on Android for azimuth/yaw and roll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537125/inconsistent-orientation-sensor-values-on-android-for-azimuth-yaw-and-roll/16418016?noredirect=1#comment34388341_16418016)

Comment: What does this really calculate? I put it in my code, hold the phone vertical and start rotating about the z-axis, the mAzimuthAngleNotFlat value wildly change. For example, initially the angle is 260, rotating  clockwise by 90 degree give around 360 and the value either stay pretty much the same when keep rotating or change to value < 90 and suddenly when the phone is upside down it is now about 270. If it is any consistent it should be 90.

Comment: If the value is in between -89 and 89 how can you get value in the range of 91 - 269 by adding 360?

Comment: It calculates azimuth when device is not flat.

Comment: azimuth of what? what is the direction with respect to magnetic north that you are interested?

Comment: Clockwise from North when device is not flat to the ground.

Comment: Of what? The accepted answer you referred to above is wrong. I did not bother to verify at that time. Do you want to obtain the direction of the device y-axis, back camera direction or what?

Comment: Device will be facing you and you will be moving from North clockwise. The angle will keep on increasing from 0(North) in clockwise direction.

The accepted answer is giving accurate value.

Comment: Only if you hold the device in a portrait position. What happen if you rotate your device when moving around? That is from portrait to landscape. Actually a small rotation would change the value considerably.

Comment: Is that what you want? The user cannot even rotate the phone slightly? You do not seem to understand what I am at, you should look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326720/compass-internal-working-in-android-devices/22341936#22341936

Comment: So, can I get right azimuth in any Orientation mode, using your answer?

Comment: You have to tell me what direction you want. What is the meaning of azimuth? For example, when the device is flat, the azimuth is the direction of the device y-axis. When the device is not flat what do you want azimuth to be the direction of? The azimuth by itself has no meaning. For example if I do AR, I want the azimuth to be the direction of the back camera, which is the negative direction of the device z-axis. So you have to tell me which direction you are interested in before I can tell you how to calculate the azimuth.

Comment: If you take a look at Orientation, it gives you Pitch, Roll and Azimuth. This azimuth is what I am calling angle from Magnetic North.

Yes, I am only able to get exact angle from North but only when device is flat to the ground and device is kept portrait. In other cases I am getting this wrong.

Comment: You did not get it wrong, you just interpret it wrong. The azimuth in this case calculate the direction of the device y-axis with respect to magnetic north. That is the angle between the World y-axis (magnetic north) and the projection of the device y-axis into the World xy plane. So if you rotate the device, the device y-coordinate change and so is the azimuth. I think if you are interested in the device z-coordinate when the device is not flat. Can you tell me what this is for?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am going to use it for Compass. How can I calculate that.

Answer (score 2):

When the device is not flat and if you want your compass direction to be the negative of the direction of the device z-axis (i.e the direction you are looking at) then the azimuth can be calculate by first call

```
remapCoordinateSystem(inR, AXIS_X, AXIS_Z, outR);
```

Then call

```
getOrientation (float[] R, float[] values)
```

passing in `outR` for the parameter `R`.

This amount to project the z-axis into the World xy plane and then calculate the angle between this projection and the World y-axis which is magnetic north.

The z-axis point in the same direction when the device is rotated around this axis, thus the azimuth should not change. Of course it will vary a little due to acceleration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me implement and test it before accepting it.

Comment: In every case, using above scenario; I will find azimuth at 0th index in orientation Matrix. Is it?

Comment: In every case, the azimuth is values[0] after calling getOrientation.

Comment: `import static android.hardware.SensorManager.AXIS_X;
import static android.hardware.SensorManager.AXIS_Z;`

Comment: I don't understand why is "AXIS_Z", not "AXIS_MINUS_Z"?