# How to convert the magnetic field vector from sensor coordinate space to camera coordinate space?

Tags: android, android-sensors, arcore, magnetometer, sensormanager

I would like to collect the magnetic field vector (i.e. x,y,z in microteslas) from the [TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD Position sensor](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position) and put it in the same coordinate system that the [Frame's](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Frame) we get from ARCore are in.

The magnetic field vector is in the [Sensor Coordinate System](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-coords). We need to get it into the Camera Coordinate System. I believe I can use the following two API's, which are provided on every camera frame (showing the NDK version I like the docs more):

- [getAndroidSensorPose()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c/group/frame#arframe_getandroidsensorpose) - Gets the pose of the Android Sensor Coordinate System in the world coordinate space for this frame. I understand this to be "SensorToWorldPose."
- [getPose()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c/group/camera#arcamera_getpose) - Gets the pose of the physical camera in world space for the latest frame. I understand this to be "CameraToWorldPose".

Below, I compute the magnetic vector in the camera coordinate system (magneticVectorInCamera). When I test it (by passing a weak magnet around the phone, and by comparing it to [iOS's CLHeading's raw x,y,z values](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clheading), I don't get values I expect. Any suggestions?

```
scene.addOnUpdateListener(frameTime -> { processFrame(this.sceneView.getArFrame()) });

public void processFrame(Frame frame) {
    if (frame.getCamera().getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the magnetic vector in sensor that we stored in the onSensorChanged() delegate
    float[] magneticVectorInSensor = {x,y,z};

    // Get sensor to world
    Pose sensorToWorldPose = frame.getAndroidSensorPose();

    // Get world to camera
    Pose cameraToWorldPose = frame.getCamera().getPose();
    Pose worldToCameraPose = cameraToWorldPose.inverse();

    // Get sensor to camera
    Pose sensorToCameraPose = sensorToWorldPose.compose(worldToCameraPose);

    // Get the magnetic vector in camera coordinate space
    float[] magneticVectorInCamera = sensorToCameraPose.rotateVector(magneticVectorInSensor);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    int sensorType = sensorEvent.sensor.getType();

    switch (sensorType) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            mMagnetometerData = sensorEvent.values.clone();
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    x = mMagnetometerData[0];
    y = mMagnetometerData[1];
    z = mMagnetometerData[2];
}
```

Here is an example log line I get from this:

```
V/processFrame: magneticVectorInSensor: [-173.21014, -138.63983, 54.873657]
V/processFrame: sensorToWorldPose: t:[x:-1.010, y:-0.032, z:-0.651], q:[x:-0.28, y:-0.62, z:-0.21, w:0.71]
V/processFrame: cameraToWorldPose: t:[x:-0.941, y:0.034, z:-0.610], q:[x:-0.23, y:0.62, z:0.66, w:-0.35]
V/processFrame: worldToCameraPose: t:[x:-0.509, y:0.762, z:-0.647], q:[x:0.23, y:-0.62, z:-0.66, w:-0.35]
V/processFrame: sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:-0.114, y:0.105, z:-1.312], q:[x:0.54, y:-0.46, z:-0.08, w:-0.70]
V/processFrame: magneticVectorInCamera: [15.159668, 56.381603, 220.96408]
```

One thing I'm confused about is why my sensoryToCamera pose is changing as I move my phone:

```
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.068, y:-0.014, z:0.083], q:[x:0.14, y:-0.65, z:-0.25, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.071, y:-0.010, z:0.077], q:[x:0.11, y:-0.66, z:-0.23, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.075, y:-0.007, z:0.070], q:[x:0.08, y:-0.68, z:-0.20, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.080, y:-0.007, z:0.061], q:[x:0.05, y:-0.69, z:-0.18, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.084, y:-0.008, z:0.052], q:[x:0.01, y:-0.69, z:-0.17, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.091, y:-0.011, z:0.045], q:[x:-0.03, y:-0.69, z:-0.17, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.094, y:-0.017, z:0.037], q:[x:-0.09, y:-0.69, z:-0.17, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.098, y:-0.026, z:0.027], q:[x:-0.16, y:-0.67, z:-0.17, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.100, y:-0.037, z:0.020], q:[x:-0.23, y:-0.65, z:-0.19, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.098, y:-0.046, z:0.012], q:[x:-0.30, y:-0.62, z:-0.20, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.096, y:-0.055, z:0.005], q:[x:-0.35, y:-0.59, z:-0.19, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.092, y:-0.061, z:-0.003], q:[x:-0.41, y:-0.56, z:-0.18, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.086, y:-0.066, z:-0.011], q:[x:-0.45, y:-0.52, z:-0.17, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.080, y:-0.069, z:-0.018], q:[x:-0.49, y:-0.49, z:-0.16, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.073, y:-0.071, z:-0.025], q:[x:-0.53, y:-0.45, z:-0.15, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.065, y:-0.072, z:-0.031], q:[x:-0.56, y:-0.42, z:-0.13, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.059, y:-0.072, z:-0.038], q:[x:-0.59, y:-0.38, z:-0.13, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.053, y:-0.071, z:-0.042], q:[x:-0.61, y:-0.35, z:-0.12, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.047, y:-0.069, z:-0.046], q:[x:-0.63, y:-0.32, z:-0.11, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.041, y:-0.067, z:-0.048], q:[x:-0.64, y:-0.28, z:-0.10, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.037, y:-0.064, z:-0.050], q:[x:-0.65, y:-0.26, z:-0.10, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.032, y:-0.060, z:-0.052], q:[x:-0.67, y:-0.23, z:-0.09, w:-0.70]
sensorToCameraPose: t:[x:0.027, y:-0.057, z:-0.054], q:[x:-0.68, y:-0.20, z:-0.08, w:-0.70]
```

Note - there are several other questions about converting the magnetic field vector into a global coordinate space (i.e. [this](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/119) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315129/convert-magnetic-field-x-y-z-values-from-device-into-global-reference-frame/15317814#15317814)), but I haven't been able to find anything for going to camera coordinate space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues with my code above.

First, I was using compose incorrectly. To transform by A and then B you do B.compose(A). With that fix I started getting consistent sensorToCameraPose's.

Second, after that fix, I had a 90° rotation between x and y. From u/inio on Reddit:

> So usually for phone form-factor devices there will be a 90° rotation between the camera coordinate system (which is defined to have +x point in the diction of the horizontal axis of the physical camera image, typically the long axis of the device) and the android sensor coordinate system (which has +y pointing away from the android navigation buttons, and +x thus along the short axis of the device). The difference you describe is an 88.8° rotation. Maybe you want the virtual camera pose? [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Arcore/comments/diu3te/how_to_convert_the_magnetic_field_vector_from/f47pwto?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

I tested with using the getDisplayOrientedPose(). With it, I get what I expect when I am in portrait mode. But, if I flip to landscape, then the coordinate system changes, and I am off by a 90° rotation. So I instead did the rotation myself.

```
public void processFrame(Frame frame) {
    if (frame.getCamera().getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the magnetic vector in sensor that we stored in the onSensorChanged() delegate
    float[] magneticVectorInSensor = {x,y,z};

    // Get sensor to world
    Pose sensorToWorldPose = frame.getAndroidSensorPose();

    // Get camera to world
    Pose cameraToWorldPose = frame.getCamera().getPose();

    // +90° rotation about Z
    // https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/535#issuecomment-418845833
    Pose CAMERA_POSE_FIX = Pose.makeRotation(0, 0, ((float) Math.sqrt(0.5f)), ((float) Math.sqrt(0.5f))); 
    Pose rotatedCameraToWorldPose = cameraToWorldPose.compose(CAMERA_POSE_FIX);

    // Get world to camera
    Pose worldToCameraPose = rotatedCameraToWorldPose.inverse();

    // Get sensor to camera
    Pose sensorToCameraPose = worldToCameraPose.compose(sensorToWorldPose);

    // Get the magnetic vector in camera coordinate space
    float[] magneticVectorInCamera = sensorToCameraPose.rotateVector(magneticVectorInSensor);
}
```