# Android lock screen orientation and leaving onCreate() untouched

Tags: android, screen

I am running something in onCreate() upon initialisation.

If a user rotates the screen, it recalls onCreate().

I want to disable screen rotation and let onCreate() run ONLY upon the initial initialisation.

Is it enough to add android:screenOrientation="portrait" to the manifest or will onCreate() still be run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in your Manifest the Phone doesnt handle orientation changes and `onCreate()` doesn't get called again.
So: YES it is enough!

You can easily check it if you set a Debug-Marker in your onCreate() and then rotate your phone!

Answer (score 0):

If you hold your `Activity` in `Portrait` or in `Landscape`, the rotation will no longer happens. So the `onCreate()` will run to the end though you will try to rotate your device

Answer (score 0):

Add in your manifest:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: What does the orientation line do exactly? Do I also need to add it?

Comment: configChanges means that the configuration change is handled by the activity itself. Without it, the activity will be restarted if there is an orientation change. You might ask, if you've specified that the orientation is "portrait" how would it ever change? It can change if you launch another activity that alters the orientation, then that new activity exits, returning you back to your activity. For example, the default image capture intent on the Samsung Galaxy S3 does that in certain orientations.  From:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885620/force-portrait-orientation-mode