# How to run android apps in landscape mode and set preffered sizes in bluestacks emulator

Tags: android, landscape-portrait, bluestacks

I use bluestacks as the emulator for debuging and testing android apps with eclipse. But the problem is that I cannot run apps in portrait mode in bluestacks. All the apps run just in landscape mode even I "changed app size" in settings to both "tablet" view and "default" view. (I am worried that my bluestacks version-beta version- has only those two modes and the "phone" view and "Large phone" view is missing- what is the reason for it? Does original versions have more views?)
However once when I changed the "LinkedIn" app view to "default", it was displayed in portrait mode on the emulator, but the whole emulator had rotated 90 degrees, so that was no use..! Please help me. I want bluestacks in Portrait !!!

Answer (score 2):

in the **system tray**, right click on blue stacks icon
in the menu, select third option "Rotate Portrait Apps"
select enable.

next time ONLY PORTRAIT APP works in portrait mode..
Try the game DOTS to test

Answer (score 1):

1. Look for the Bluestack icon in the system tray.

[image]

2. Right click on the Icon and you will get a menu, hover the mouse on the "Rotate Portrait App" and you can select the following options as per your requirement.

[image]

a. **Automatic** - Selected By Default - It will rotate the app player in portrait mode for portrait apps.

b. **Disabled** - It will force the portrait apps to work in landscape mode.

c. **Enabled** - It will force the portrait apps to work in portrait mode only.

To force the emulator to run activity in **portrait** mood, you have to define the attribute `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in manifest file.

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

After doing this, the particular activity runs on portrait mood.

The important thing is, **YOU CAN'T ROTATE BLUESTACK EMULATOR JUST AS THE DEFAULT EMULATOR**

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative I found was to use "Youwave Android" instead of Bluestacks as an emulator. Youwave is provided the facility to change the orientation easily( but it configuring it is bit tricky and difficult).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here. I tried to change the screen orientation of the android launcher in bluestacks as well as its main settings. You might have to work with your coding to program its screen orientation. This link might help you as well. [Force "portrait" orientation mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885620/force-portrait-orientation-mode)

Comment: My intention was not to change the orientation via coding...!!

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga, considering this is a site for people who code, the answer seems reasonable.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSanchez The coders even require sometimes running apps without doing changes in code to do that, so as to debug and test applications and u have to understand that testing and debugging is also a simultaneous activity that coders have to do.. And additionally 21522 count of views for this question proves that requirement as stackoverflow is a site for coders..

Comment: 21522 views prove that 21522 people saw thus question. Nothing else.

Comment: That much number of people saw the question, because they searched for it(searched for a solution for it), because they too had the same problem... And this guy jayjay1303 has had the same problem/requirement and had also tried for it, but at the end seems had to satisfied with the given solution.. Simple Logics..!!!