# Orientation declare for activity doesn't work

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-orientation

I've declared inside manifest of my project, for each activity

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

but when i launch my app, if i turn device in landscape, also orientation of my app change. How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you post full manifest?

Comment: May [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885620/force-portrait-orientation-mode) will help you in your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another easy way to achieve that the Activities don't change orientation is to call

```
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

in the onCreate() method of all activities that should not change their orientation.

Comment: ok, it works. But why if i put that string inside manifest, orientation doesn't work