# Android - Force portrait view in landscape orientation

Tags: java, android, android-orientation

I'm working on an android Amazon Fire TV app, and for debug purposes, I'd like to force a portrait view orientation inside of the permanent landscape 16:9 display.

Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: declare on manifest http://stackoverflow.com/a/4885663/3640637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your manifest file inside  your activity tag

> android:screenOrientation="portrait"