# How can I display my program from the taller part of the devices screen

Tags: android

Some android devices are as follows such as the tablets:

[image]

And the height is smaller than the width physically. I want to display my program and all the its activities only from the taller part of the all android devices.

If I use `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in manifest, will be displayed my program as above in the tablet?

Comment: I have no idea what "taller part" is supposed to mean... And what you are saying is not correct at all. If you hold a tablet in portrait orientation than the width will be smaller than the height just like on a phone. There is no absolute default orientation which permanently defines which side is the width and which is the height, it all just depends on which way you are holding the device.

Comment: The term you are looking for is 'orientation'.  You can configure your app to operate in either Portrait or Landscape orientation or both.  See this question for more details ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885620/force-portrait-orientation-mode

Comment: I updated my post.please see.

Comment: What. How did you get that `java` user name? How is that not reserved or taken?

Comment: @Jared Burrows your answer is a spam and not a scientific answer

Comment: @java That is a comment and not an answer. I was just asking a question.

Comment: btw are you looking for a scientific answer? omg and to answer your question why don't you try it and see