# When exiting app, change orientation from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

So I manually set the orientation in the onCreate to portrait in my app:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

but I want to change (force) the layout back to landscape when I exit the application. **Currently, if my device is locked in landscape and it changes to portrait mode when the app is started** I want to be able to go back to landscape. And also vice versa, on onResume I want it to go back to portrait. Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: here is where I try to manually set the orientation back to landscape when I exit the application, but the orientation does not change. When I boot the kernel image its default is landscape orientation but when I change the orientation within an app, the orientation sets it globally on application menu and home screen.

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("Position", myVideoView.getCurrentPosition());
        myVideoView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
        myVideoView.seekTo(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "-- ON DESTROY --");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "-- ON PAUSE --");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "-- ON STOP --");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force "portrait" orientation mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885620/force-portrait-orientation-mode)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. When I exit the app, the screen orientation stays as portrait.

Comment: Are you sure your question is regarding your code and not your device's settings?

Comment: I'm running off a embedded kernel for Android 4.4. The build does not have a setting for orientation since there is no onboard accelerometer

Comment: did  you try setting that on `onStop()`?

Comment: I tried this: `@Override
 public void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  super.onConfigurationChanged(config_change);
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "-- ON STOP --");
 }`

Comment: Could you edit your question with more relevant code and context of what happens? Also noting that you are running a custom build is important and some info about it would be useful. The comments are no place to do this.

Comment: Running an ARM Linux-3.10.53 Kernel Image for the Freescale i.mx6qSabreLite board