# Changing the screen orientation in the Android Manifest does not have any effects

Tags: android, android-manifest, screen-orientation

I would like to have my app only in landscape mode. For that I use the suggested code in the Android manifest that is recommended here [Force "portrait" orientation mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885620/force-portrait-orientation-mode)

However, on the Android emulator the layout is always in portrait mode. Even if I rotate the Emulator, the layout orientation does not change. Any idea why this problem occurs?

Here you can see the Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nikhiljain.canvasdrawingsample">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CanvasDrawingSample">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is the main file:

```
package com.nikhiljain.canvasdrawingsample

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the issues is with closing tag <activity android:name=".MainActivity">. Remove closing tag > after ".MainActivity"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing `<activity` tag too soon, rest of attributes (besides `name`) are outside declaration and "doesn't count":

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">      <----- !!!!
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

should be:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```